# Extracting a value from text based on training data?

Tags: python

I have a large structured dataset with 2 columns containing:

1. A paragraph of text with various text and integers
2. A integer that's found in the text within the first column

What I want to do is train model that can extract the correct integer from future text ideally in Python. I have come across NER but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of open questions based on your OP.

1. How does a structured column look like containing the text and integers ?
   What sort of text is there?
2. Is there a criteria based on which this integer has to be extracted.

If the data in column A is symmetrical across all rows containing structured data, then may be a regex expression can extract the intended integer.

PS- this assumes that the text follows the same structure.
That's why a peak into a sample of the dataset might help to better gauge the problem at hand and figure out an appropriate algorithm, if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Mistype in my part, I was meant to write unstructured. An example of the original table and the parsed data can be shown here: https://imgur.com/a/2ZY86MR. I basically ran the picture through OCR and got the text as so.

And no, unfortunately there is no criteria apart from trying to extract the same specific value. I should also add due to the many formats the data has been uploaded in e.g, some in tables some not etc. I have no way in formatting this data without manually going through it. That's how I came about getting the 2500 long dataset.